# How ammonia can be in equilibrium if formation of ammonia is spontaneous in one way?

Tags: thermodynamics

If a process is spontaneous under certain condition, the reverse process is non-spontaneous. Under standard conditions, it can be calculated that the formation of ammonia from nitrogen and hydrogen is spontaneous.

How equilibrium happens in this situation as formation of nitrogen and hydrogen from ammonia is non-spontaneous?

I mean why the reverse reaction occurs (formation of $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{H2}$ from ammonia) as it is non-spontaneous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are asking about formation of ammonia from hydrogen and nitrogen.
Then you can write a reaction like this:

$$\ce{3H2_{(g)} + N2_{(g)} -> 2NH3_{(g)}}$$

Where I am indicating that ammonia is being produced.

Using our knowledge of thermodynamics we can write:

$$\Delta G_{\mathrm r} = \Delta G_{\mathrm r}^\circ + RT \ln \left[\frac{(p_\ce{NH3})^2}{(p_\ce{N2})(p_\ce{H2})^3}\right]$$

Where those pressures are the ones you have initially, at some temperature $T$.

So, as you say, if Gibbs free energy of reaction ($\Delta G_\mathrm r$) is negative the formation of ammonia in that condition will be spontaneous, but that will be until $\Delta G_\mathrm r$ is zero, then the system reaches equilibrium (and there is no spontaneous process). Mathematically:

$$\Delta G_{\mathrm r} = \Delta G_{\mathrm r}^\circ + RT \ln \left[\frac{(p_\ce{NH3})^2}{(p_\ce{N2})(p_\ce{H2})^3}\right] = 0$$
and
$$ \Delta G_{\mathrm r}^\circ = -RT \ln \left[\frac{(p_\ce{NH3})^2}{(p_\ce{N2})(p_\ce{H2})^3}\right]$$

where the pressures here are equilibrium pressures. Now the reaction should be written as:

$$\ce{3H2_{(g)} + N2_{(g)} <=> 2NH3_{(g)}}$$

Comment: Correct, only issue is it's 2 NH3 in the equation, not just 1

Comment: good..thanks..If you want to edit there won't be any problem..

Comment: i understand this calculation . but , as we know that whenever NH3 produced , the reverse reaction also happens to occur .That is formation of H2 and N2 back. But this reverse reaction is not spontaneous (the forward reaction is). so, why this reverse reaction occurs?

Comment: @AsifAhmed spontaneity only refers to the **net** forward reaction being favoured

Comment: @orthocresol so it doesn't matter whether reverse reaction(formation of H2 and N2 from NH3) is present ?

Comment: @AsifAhmed What $\Delta G$ indicates is what direction of the reaction will be spontaneous in the initial conditions you specify (first equation)..anyway, it can be confusing..

Comment: @hernan Miraola .Thank you for your answers.under certain condition , change in free energy indicates that the reaction is forwardly favored (that is , the production of more NH3). But in chemical kinetics , we learn that both the forward and reverse reaction are present(though not same rate , but both still present). so is this situation like this- both reaction is present , but net reaction is forward?

Comment: yes, you are right..@AsifAhmed. As orthocresol said, we are talking about the net process..